Run Config on eclipse ide
I'm writing code in eclipse cdt and I want to make a run configuration that includes every project. So for example, you made configuration and it could run project a and b in one configuration.
I am not that familiar with eclipse cdt, so I tried like %FILENAME% on config, but it didn't work.
